# Finding Duplicated value acorss groups in Pandas GroupBy

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
                         'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
                   'B': ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
                         'two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],
                   'C': [3,4,5,8,10,12,14,12]})
df.groupby(['A','B']).sum()
```

[image]

How to find if the values in the C column is repeated in other groups as well?
(Here 12 is repeated in both the groups)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. To make it easier for the community to answer your question, please add a (minimal) example dataset - as data (or better yet, as code that produces it) and not as an image. To learn more, please visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples. I'd be more than happy to remove my downvote and try to answer when you do so, so tag me in comments when you do.

Comment: @ItamarMushkin updated the dataset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is convert `MultIndex` to 3 columns `DataFrame`, then [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with remove non duplicated rows by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and common values are in index:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
                         'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
                   'B': ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
                         'two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],
                   'C': [3,4,5,8,10,12,14,12]})
df = df.groupby(['A','B']).sum()

common = df.reset_index().pivot('C','A','B').dropna().index
print (common)
Int64Index([12], dtype='int64', name='C')
```

Then if want filter original data use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['C'].isin(common)]
print (df)
            C
A   B        
bar two    12
foo three  12
```

If want common rows duplicated at least in 2 groups solution is:

```
print (df)  
     A      B   C
0  foo    one   3
1  bar    one   4
2  foo    two   3
3  bar  three   8
4  foo    two  14
5  bar    two  12
6  foo    one  14
7  foo  three  12
8  xxx    yyy   8

df = df.groupby(['A','B']).sum()
print (df)
            C
A   B        
bar one     4
    three   8 <- dupe per bar, three
    two    12 <- dupe per bar, two
foo one    17 <-17 is duplicated per group foo, one, so omited
    three  12 <- dupe per foo, three
    two    17 <-17 is duplicated per group foo, one, so omited
xxx yyy     8 <- dupe per xxx, yyy
```

---

```
common1 = (df.reset_index()
             .pivot_table(index='C',columns='A', values='B', aggfunc='size')
             .notna()
             .sum(axis=1)
            )
common1 = common1.index[common1.gt(1)]
print (common1)
Int64Index([8, 12], dtype='int64', name='C')

df1 = df[df['C'].isin(common1)]
print (df1)
            C
A   B        
bar three   8
    two    12
foo three  12
xxx yyy     8
```

Answer (score 2):

To show a more instructive example, I added one row to your source DataFrame,
so that it contains:

```
     A      B   C
0  foo    one   3
1  bar    one   4
2  foo    two   5
3  bar  three   8
4  foo    two  10
5  bar    two  12
6  foo    one  14
7  foo  three  12
8  xxx    yyy   8
```

I saved the result of grouping in another DataFrame:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['A','B']).sum()
```

so it contains:

```
            C
A   B        
bar one     4
    three   8
    two    12
foo one    17
    three  12
    two    15
xxx yyy     8
```

So as you can see, there are two repeted values in *C*: *12* and *8*.
Note that now the index in *df2* is **unique**.

Then, to show the repeating values and their groups, run:

```
df2[df2.duplicated(keep=False)].sort_values('C')
```

getting:

```
            C
A   B        
bar three   8
xxx yyy     8
bar two    12
foo three  12
```

The above result shows all repeated values and groups (*A* and *B*)
in which they are.

Comment: Your solution also parse duplicated per one group, so is wrong. Check edited m yanswer, your solution also parse `17` row, it parse all dupes, not dupes per groups.